# what are the characteristics of this random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, random-functions, chi-squared

Consider independent sequences of independent and identically distributed
(i.i.d.) zero-mean Gaussian random scalars $r_{i}\sim\mathcal{N}(\theta,\sigma^{2})$
and $\rho\sim\mathcal{N}(0,a^{2})$. Consider the following variable
\begin{eqnarray*}
L & = & b((\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}r_{i})+\rho)^{2},
\end{eqnarray*}
where $b,n$ are positive scalars. What are the characteristics of
$L$ please? Does the probability density function of $L$ is $F$
non central please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $r_i \sim \text{IID } \mathcal{N} (\theta, \sigma^2)$ you have:

$$\bar{r}_n \equiv \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n r_i \sim \mathcal{N} \Big( \theta, \frac{\sigma^2}{n} \Big).$$

Since $\rho \sim \mathcal{N} (0, a^2)$ you then have $\bar{r}_n + \rho \sim \mathcal{N} ( \theta, a^2 + \sigma^2 / n )$ so that:

$$\frac{\bar{r}_n + \rho}{\sqrt{a^2 + \sigma^2 / n}} \sim \mathcal{N} \Bigg( \frac{\theta}{\sqrt{a^2 + \sigma^2 / n}}, 1 \Bigg).$$

Hence, your random variable has a scaled [non-central chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution):

$$L \equiv b (\bar{r}_n + \rho)^2 \sim b (a^2 + \sigma^2 / n)  \cdot \chi_1^2 \Big( \frac{\theta^2}{a^2 + \sigma^2 / n} \Big) .$$

Comment: why did the mean still be equal to \theta after dividing by the square root expression please?

Comment: Sorry, that was an error - I have edited the answer to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

1. $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n r_i \sim N(\theta, \sigma^2/n)$ (why?)
2. $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n r_i + \rho \sim N(\theta, a^2 + \sigma^2/n)$ (assuming $\rho$ is independent of the $r_i$)
3. $\sqrt{b} \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n r_i + \rho\right) \sim N(\sqrt{b}\theta, b(a^2 + \sigma^2/n))$
4. Square the above and note that it is a particular non-central chi squared random variable with 1 degree of freedom.

Comment: [Jinx!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinx_(children%27s_game))